# less-style markdown viewer for UNIX systems

Tags: node.js, bash, unix, markdown, less-unix

I have a Markdown string in JavaScript, and I'd like to display it (with bolding, etc) in a `less` (or, I suppose, `more`)-style viewer for the command line.

For example, with a string

```
"hello\n" + 
"_____\n" + 
"*world*!"
```

I would like to have output pop up with scrollable content that looks like

> ### hello
>
> *world*

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: Do you really want bold and ital? How can you get that in `less`? Good luck.

Comment: `less` can certainly display bold and underline; see how man pages are displayed.  You just need to convert markdown to something `less` can handle, perhaps with `nroff` as an intermediate step.

Comment: kind of similar question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4140/4667

Answer (score 68):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can convert Markdown to groff man pages.

This (thanks to nenopera's comment):

```
 pandoc -s -f markdown -t man foo.md | man -l -
```

should do the trick.  The `-s` option tells it to generate proper headers and footers.

There may be other markdown-to-*roff converters out there; Pandoc just happens to be the first one I found.

Another alternative is the `markdown` command (`apt-get install markdown` on Debian systems), which converts Markdown to HTML. For example:

```
markdown README.md | lynx -stdin
```

(assuming you have the `lynx` terminal-based web browser).

Or (thanks to Danny's suggestion) you can do something like this:

```
markdown README.md > README.html && xdg-open README.html
```

where `xdg-open` (on some systems) opens the specified file or URL in the preferred application. This will probably open `README.html` in your preferred GUI web browser (which isn't exactly "less-style", but it might be useful).

Comment: Really great, and not only for markdown to man. But If you don't want to screw you up, this is the some-pandoc-command: pandoc -s -f markdown -t man <file>. Really Important -s which add header of man (or it wont  work) better use pandoc-command | man -l - (better page width)

Comment: Works for me on Linux, but the version of `man` in Mac OS X (and probably other BSDs) doesn't support the local-file mode (`man -l `). Here's the closest I could come for Mac OS X: pandoc -s -f markdown -t man foo.md | groff -T utf8 -man | less

Comment: +1 for metamatt's comment - this can also be used to write a less filter. Try, for example, saving the following as .lessfilter
<pre><code>
    #!/bin/sh
    
    case "$1" in
        *.md)
            extension-handler "$1"
            pandoc -s -f markdown -t man "$1"|groff -T utf8 -man -
            ;;
        *)
            # We don't handle this format.
            exit 1
    esac
    
    # No further processing by lesspipe necessary
    exit 0
</pre></code>
Then, you can type `less FILENAME.md` and it will be formatted like a manpage.

Comment: if you have a browser that responds to the `open` command: `markdown README.md > ~/readme.html && open ~/readme.html`

Comment: @Danny: Good point, see my updated answer. (On my Ubuntu system, `open` is equivalent to `openvt`, which opens a virtual terminal; `xdg-open` works as described.)

Comment: Thanks to this answer I have `function md () { markdown $1 | lynx --stdin; }` in my `.bashrc` now. The needed dependencies have a low footprint, which is nice on constrained boxes. You may check, if `w3m` or `links` are already available on your machine.

Comment: +1 for `markdown` + `lynx` solution. Easiest to use with OS X & homebrew after `brew install markdown lynx` :)

Answer (score 32):

I tried to write this in a comment above, but I couldn't format my code block correctly. To write a 'less filter', try, for example, saving the following as `~/.lessfilter`:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    *.md)
        extension-handler "$1"
        pandoc -s -f markdown -t man "$1"|groff -T utf8 -man -
        ;;
    *)
        # We don't handle this format.
        exit 1
esac

# No further processing by lesspipe necessary
exit 0
```

Then, you can type `less FILENAME.md` and it will be formatted like a manpage.

Comment: Don't forget to `chmod +x` `.lessfilter`. Also, `less -R` may be needed.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Not only solves the original problem, but added a new skill to my bag of tricks! Bring on the less filters!

Comment: I had to add `-K utf8` switch to groff (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24969648/1581629) or my lists would diplay things such as "â   âââ"

Answer (score 9):

If you are into **colors** then maybe this is worth checking as well:

[terminal_markdown_viewer](https://github.com/axiros/terminal_markdown_viewer)

[image]

It can be used straightforward also from within other programs, or python modules.

And it has a *lot* of styles, like over 200 for markdown and code which can be combined.

[image: pic2]

#### Disclaimer

- It is pretty alpha there may be still bugs
- I'm the author of it, maybe some people like it ;-)

Answer (score 5):

A totally different alternative is [mad](https://github.com/visionmedia/mad). It is a shell script I've just discovered. It's very easy to install and it does render markdown in a console pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a couple functions based on [Keith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7603703/65387):

```
mdt() {
    markdown "$*" | lynx -stdin
}

mdb() {
    local TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
    markdown "$*" > $TMPFILE && ( xdg-open $TMPFILE > /dev/null 2>&1 & )
}
```

If you're using `zsh`, just place those two functions in `~/.zshrc` and then call them from your terminal like

```
mdt README.md
mdb README.md
```

"t" is for "terminal", "b" is for browser.

Answer (score 1):

Using OSX I prefer to use this command

```
brew install pandoc
pandoc -s -f markdown -t man README.md | groff -T utf8 -man | less
```

Convert markupm, format document with groff, and pipe into less

credit: http://blog.metamatt.com/blog/2013/01/09/previewing-markdown-files-from-the-terminal/

Answer (score 1):

### This is an alias that encapsulates a function:

```
alias mdless='_mdless() { if [ -n "$1" ] ; then if [ -f "$1" ] ; then cat <(echo ".TH $1 7 `date --iso-8601` Dr.Beco Markdown") <(pandoc -t man $1) | groff -K utf8 -t -T utf8 -man 2>/dev/null | less ; fi ; fi ;}; _mdless '
```

### Explanation

- `alias mdless='...'` : creates an alias for `mdless`
- `_mdless() {...};` : creates a temporary function to be called afterwards
- `_mdless` : at the end, call it (the function above)

Inside the function:

- `if [ -n "$1" ] ; then` : if the first argument is not null then...
- `if [ -f "$1" ] ; then` : also, if the file exists and is regular then...
- `cat arg1 arg2 | groff` ... : cat sends this two arguments concatenated to groff; the arguments being:

  - arg1: `<(echo ".TH $1 7`date --iso-8601`Dr.Beco Markdown")` : something that starts the file and `groff` will understand as the header and footer notes. This substitutes the empty header from `-s` key on `pandoc`.
  - arg2: `<(pandoc -t man $1)` : the file itself, filtered by `pandoc`, outputing the `man` style of file `$1`
- `| groff -K utf8 -t -T utf8 -man 2>/dev/null` : piping the resulting concatenated file to `groff`:

  - `-K utf8` so `groff` understands the input file code
  - `-t` so it displays correctly tables in the file
  - `-T utf8` so it output in the correct format
  - `-man` so it uses the *MACRO* package to outputs the file in `man` format
  - `2>/dev/null` to ignore errors (after all, its a raw file being transformed in man by hand, we don't care the errors as long as we can see the file in a not-so-much-ugly format).
- `| less` : finally, shows the file paginating it with `less` (I've tried to avoid this pipe by using `groffer` instead of `groff`, but `groffer` is not as robust as `less` and some files hangs it or do not show at all. So, let it go through one more pipe, what the heck!

Add it to your `~/.bash_aliases` (or alike)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
id=$(uuidgen | cut -c -8)
markdown $1 > /tmp/md-$id
google-chrome --app=file:///tmp/md-$id
```

It renders the markdown into HTML, puts it into a file in `/tmp/md-...` and opens that in a kiosk chrome session with no URI bar etc.. You just pass the md file as an argument or pipe it into stdin. Requires markdown and Google Chrome. Chromium should also work but you need to replace the last line with

```
chromium-browser --app=file:///tmp/md-$id
```

If you wanna get fancy about it, you can use some css to make it look nice, I edited the script and made it use Bootstrap3 (overkill) from a CDN.

```
#!/bin/bash
id=$(uuidgen | cut -c -8)
markdown $1 > /tmp/md-$id
sed -i "1i <html><head><style>body{padding:24px;}</style><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css\"></head><body>" /tmp/md-$id
echo "</body>" >> /tmp/md-$id
google-chrome --app=file:///tmp/md-$id > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: I'd suggest to replace the uuid hack with `mktemp` which is actually safe and best practice; also it would give you a full pathname which you can `rm` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

*I'll post [my unix page answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364469/119183) here, too:*

An IMHO heavily underestimated command line markdown viewer is the [markdown-cli](https://github.com/cilice/markdown-cli).

## Installation

```
npm install markdown-cli --global
```

## Usage

```
markdown-cli <file>
```

## Features

Probably not noticed much, because it misses any documentation...
But as far as I could figure out by some example markdown files, some things that convinced me:

- handles ill formatted files much better (similarly to atom, github, etc.; eg. when blank lines are missing before lists)
- more stable with formatting in headers or lists (bold text in lists breaks sublists in some other viewers)
- proper table formatting
- syntax highlightning
- resolves footnote links to show the link instead of the footnote number (not everyone might want this)

## Screenshot

[image: example.png]

## Drawbacks

I have realized the following issues

- code blocks are flattened (all leading spaces disappear)
- two blank lines appear before lists