# How can I test what my readme.md file will look like before committing to GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am writing a readme for my GitHub project in the .md format. Is there a way can I test what my readme.md file will look like before committing to GitHub?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Many ways: If you're on a Mac, use [Mou](http://25.io/mou/).

If you want to test in a browser, you could try [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/), as pointed out by @Aaron or [Dillinger](http://dillinger.io/) since [Notepag](http://notepag.es) seems to be down now. Personally I use Dillinger since it just works and saves all my documents in my browser's local database.

Comment: dillinger.io also seems to be down now, although it is still the first listed when you google "markdown online viewer", so it might just be me. I successfully used https://stackedit.io/ to preview and edit my readme.md.

Comment: StackEdit formats "definition lists", github doesn't. StackEdit puts triple backtick code blocks on there own line (useful for use in numbered lists), github doesn't. There are other differences. The only safe bet is to trial and error with a gist and delete it when you are done.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like Mou support MacOS Mojave (10.14)

Comment: MacDown is a great alternative to Mou. The developer states that the application is inspired by Mou so they are pretty similar. For me the transition was smooth https://macdown.uranusjr.com

Comment: Make sure you're using `README` **.md** and not `README`**.rst** for **StackEdit*

Answer (score 107):

**Visual Studio Code** has the option to edit and preview md file changes. Since VS Code is platform independent, this would work for Windows, Mac and Linux.

> To switch between views, press **Ctrl+Shift+V** in the editor. You can view the preview side-by-side **(Ctrl+K V)** with the file you are editing and see changes reflected in real-time as you edit.

Also...

> Q: Does VS Code support GitHub Flavored Markdown?
>
> A: No, VS Code targets the CommonMark Markdown specification using the markdown-it library. GitHub is moving toward the CommonMark specification.

[image]

The preview button is this: [image]

[More details here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown)

Answer (score 103):

[**Atom**](https://atom.io/) works nicely out of the box - just open the Markdown file and hit **Ctrl+Shift+M** to toggle the Markdown preview panel next to it. It handles HTML and images also.

[image: Atom screenshot]

Comment: brew cask install atom

Comment: perfs already had Atom installed just typed `atom .` and right clicked the readme > `Markdown Preview`

Comment: Atom rules the roost. None of stackedit, Dillinger, or typora supported collapsible sections via HTML `<details>` tags. Atom does and looks better than the rest to boot.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+M didn't work for me for some reason. Had to open the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and select markdown preview from there. Thanks!

Comment: Also works with VS Code. Open a .md file in vs code and you will see a new button appear at the top right side of your screen. Otherwise simply, Right-click the file and select 'open preview' to preview your .md files.

Comment: Came here to say atom (the code editor) is dead now. They "sunset" it https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/

Answer (score 56):

I just found a very useful CLI tool for rendering GitHub flavored markdown: [grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip). It uses GitHub's API, thus renders quite well.

Frankly, the developer of [grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip), has a more elaborate answer on these very similar questions:

- [Is there a command line utility for rendering GitHub flavored Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694887/is-there-a-command-line-utility-for-rendering-github-flavored-markdown)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871865/whats-the-best-way-to-edit-githubs-readme-md

Answer (score 39):

I usually just edit it on the GitHub website directly and click "Preview" just above the editing window.

Perhaps that's a new feature that's been added since this post was made.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that GitHub (so far) shows inline diffs of the changes which makes a preview quite unusable if you want to get an impression of how the changes look like and not what actually changed.

Comment: @B12Toaster You can create a new file on the repository using GitHub website (without saving it) and name it `xxx.md` and paste your code there.
File extension is `.md` so you can preview your changes.
You will update util you finish, then copy the file content and paste it over the original `readme.md` file.

Comment: An additional issue is that it does not accurately display everything. One concrete example: if you are centering an image at the top using `<div align='center'><img ...></div>` it will not show it centered in the preview, it will be left-aligned. You have to save it to see it accurately, which makes the preview untrustworthy in my opinion.

Answer (score 12):

#### VS Code

Mac: `Command + Shift + V`

Windows: `Ctrl + Shift + V`

#### Detailed Instructions

Open the `.md` file in VS Code. With the file selected, use the keyboard shortcuts above.

Answer (score 6):

I use a locally hosted HTML file to preview GitHub readmes.

I looked at several existing options, but decided to roll my own to meet the following requirements:

- Single file
- Locally hosted (intranet) URL
- No browser extension required
- No locally hosted server-side processing (for example, no PHP)
- Lightweight (for example, no jQuery)
- High fidelity: use GitHub to render the Markdown, and same CSS

I keep local copies of my GitHub repositories in sibling directories under a "github" directory.

Each repo directory contains a README.md file:

```
.../github/
           repo-a/
                  README.md
           repo-b/
                  README.md
           etc.
```

The github directory contains the "preview" HTML file:

```
.../github/
           readme.html
```

To preview a readme, I browse github/readme.html, specifying the repo in the query string:

```
http://localhost/github/readme.html?repo-a
```

Alternatively, you can copy the readme.html into the same directory as the README.md, and omit the query string:

```
http://localhost/github/repo-a/readme.html
```

If the readme.html is in the same directory as README.md, you don't even need to serve readme.html over HTTP: you can just open it directly from your file system.

The HTML file uses the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/#render-a-markdown-document-in-raw-mode) to render the Markdown in a README.md file. There's a [rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting): at the time of writing, **60 requests per hour**.

Works for me in current production versions of Chrome, IE, and Firefox on Windows 7.

### Source

Here's the HTML file (readme.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
     Preview a GitHub README.md.

     Either:

     -  Copy this file to a directory that contains repo directories,
        and then specify a repo name in the query string.

        For example:

          http://localhost/github/readme.html?myrepo

     or

     -  Copy this file to the directory that contains a README.md,
        and then browse to this file without specifying a query string.

        For example:

          http://localhost/github/myrepo/readme.html

        (or just open this file in your browser directly from
        your file system, without HTTP)
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<meta name="author" content="Graham Hannington"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<title>GitHub readme preview</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://primercss.io/docs.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var HTTP_STATUS_OK = 200;
var URL_API_GITHUB_RENDER_MARKDOWN = "https://api.github.com/markdown/raw";
var README_FILE_NAME = "README.md";

var readmeURL;

var queryString = location.search.substring(1);

if (queryString.length > 0) {
  readmeURL = queryString + "/" + README_FILE_NAME;
} else {
  readmeURL = README_FILE_NAME;
}

// Get Markdown, then render it as HTML
function getThenRenderMarkdown(markdownURL) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", markdownURL, true);
  xhr.responseType = "text";
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == HTTP_STATUS_OK) {
     // Response text contains Markdown
      renderMarkdown(this.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

// Use the GitHub API to render Markdown as HTML
function renderMarkdown(markdown) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", URL_API_GITHUB_RENDER_MARKDOWN, true);
  xhr.responseType = "html";
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == HTTP_STATUS_OK) {
      document.getElementById("readme").innerHTML = this.response;
    }
  }
  xhr.send(markdown);
}

window.onload = function() {
  getThenRenderMarkdown(readmeURL);
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header class="masthead">
<div class="container">
<span class="masthead-logo"><span class="mega-octicon
octicon-mark-github"></span>GitHub readme preview</span>
</div>
</header>
<div class="container">
<div id="readme" class="markdown-body">
<p>Rendering markdown, please wait...</p>
</div>
<footer class="footer">Rendering by
<a href="https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/">GitHub</a>,
styling by <a href="http://primercss.io/">Primer</a>.</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Developer notes

- Typically, I wrap my code in an IIFE, but in this case, I didn't see the need, and thought I'd keep it concise
- I haven't bothered supporting backlevel IE
- For conciseness, I have omitted the error handling code (do you believe me?!)
- I'd welcome JavaScript programming tips

### Ideas

- I'm considering creating a GitHub repository for this HTML file, and putting the file in the gh-pages branch, so that GitHub serves it as a "normal" web page. I'd tweak the file to accept a complete URL - of the README (or any other Markdown file) - as the query string. I'm curious to see whether being hosted by GitHub would sidestep the GitHub API request limit, and whether I run afoul of cross-domain issues (using an Ajax request to get the Markdown from a different domain than the domain serving the HTML page).

---

## Original version (deprecated)

I've preserved this record of the original version for curiosity value.
This version had the following issues that are solved in the current version:

- It required some related files to be downloaded
- It didn't support being dropped into the same directory as the README.md
- Its HTML was more brittle; more susceptible to changes in GitHub

The github directory contains the "preview" HTML file and related files:

```
.../github/
           readme-preview.html
           github.css
           github2.css
           octicons.eot
           octicons.svg
           octicons.woff
```

I downloaded the CSS and octicons font files from GitHub:

```
https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github- ... .css
https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/github2- ... .css
https://github.com/static/fonts/octicons/octicons.* (eot, woff, svg)
```

I renamed the CSS files to omit the long string of hex digits in the original names.

I edited github.css to refer to the local copies of the octicons font files.

I examined the HTML of a GitHub page, and reproduced enough of the HTML structure surrounding the readme content to provide reasonable fidelity; for example, the constrained width.

The GitHub CSS, octicons font, and HTML "container" for the readme content are moving targets: I will need to periodically download new versions.

I toyed with using CSS from various GitHub projects. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="http://rawgit.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css/gh-pages/github-markdown.css">
```

but eventually decided to use the CSS from GitHub itself.

### Source

Here's the HTML file (readme-preview.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Preview a GitHub README.md.
     Copy this file to a directory that contains repo directories.
     Specify a repo name in the query string. For example:

     http://localhost/github/readme-preview.html?myrepo
-->
<html>
<head>
<title>Preview GitHub readme</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<!-- Downloaded copies of the CSS files served by GitHub.
     In github.css, the @font-face for font-family:'octicons'
     has been edited to refer to local copies of the font files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="github.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="github2.css"/>
<style>
body {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var HTTP_STATUS_OK = 200;
var URL_API_GITHUB_RENDER_MARKDOWN = "https://api.github.com/markdown/raw";
var README_FILE_NAME = "README.md";

var repo = location.search.substring(1);

// Get Markdown, then render it as HTML
function getThenRenderMarkdown() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", repo + "/" + README_FILE_NAME, true);
  xhr.responseType = "text";
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == HTTP_STATUS_OK) {
     // Response text contains Markdown
      renderMarkdown(this.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

// Use the GitHub API to render Markdown as HTML
function renderMarkdown(markdown) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", URL_API_GITHUB_RENDER_MARKDOWN, true);
  xhr.responseType = "html";
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == HTTP_STATUS_OK) {
      document.getElementById("readme-content").innerHTML = this.response;
    }
  }
  xhr.send(markdown);
}

window.onload = getThenRenderMarkdown;
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The following HTML structure was copied from live GitHub page on 2015-12-01,
     except for the "readme-content" id of the article element,
     which was coined for this preview page.-->
<div class="main-content" role="main">
<div class="container repo-container new-discussion-timeline experiment-repo-nav">
<div class="repository-content">
<div id="readme" class="boxed-group flush clearfix announce instapaper_body md">
<h3><span class="octicon octicon-book"></span>README.md</h3>
<article class="markdown-body entry-content"
         itemprop="mainContentOfPage"
         id="readme-content"><p>Rendering markdown...</p></article>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 2012 (when this question was created) GitHub itself can:

- create and display a *preview* of a Markdown document in a regular repository (it always did, [since Aug. 2011](https://github.blog/2011-08-15-edit-like-an-ace/))
- or, if you don't want to impact directly your repository, do the same with [**gist**](https://gist.github.com/) ([since Dec. 2020](https://github.blog/2012-12-11-welcome-to-a-new-gist/))
  Even without committing a gist, you can, since Nov. 2021, preview a [Markdown document in a Gist](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-17-preview-the-markdown-rendering-of-gists/) you are editing (but not yet committing)

[image: https://i1.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/1767415/141661660-d5eb7cbe-7d98-404f-a4ea-cef648c005ee.png?ssl=1]

Once the preview of that gist looks good, you can copy the markdown from said gist to your local `README.md`, add, commit and push.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Pycharm (or another Jetbrains IDE like Intellij, RubyMine, PHPStorm, etc), there are multiple free plugins for Markdown support right in your IDE that allow real-time preview while editing. The Markdown Navigator plugin is quite good. If you open an .md file in the IDE, recent versions will offer to install supporting plugins and show you the list.

Comment: For the latest Pycharm it seems to support it out of the box (no plugins needed).

Answer (score 1):

**SublimeText 2/3**

Install package: `Markdown Preview`

Options:

- Preview in browser.
- Export to html.
- Copy to clipboard.

Comment: This works well because it supports github, gitlab, and generic markdown. Although it is difficult to install.

Answer (score 1):

An [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47303576/) answer suggested **Markdown Preview**, a plugin for **[Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/)***, but failed to mention its significance compared to other tools:

[Markdown Preview](https://github.com/facelessuser/MarkdownPreview) supports GFM, [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/about-writing-and-formatting-on-github) ([specs](https://github.github.com/gfm/)), alongside "standard" Markdown (aka CommonMark), which is of particular relevance if you want to know what your `.md` files will look like *on GitHub specifically* – because variants like GFM render slightly differently due to their support of extra features (additional elements, site-specific formatting).

To preview GitHub Flavored Markdown locally with Markdown Preview, you need to be online and able to connect to the [GitHub Markdown API](https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/). Because unauthenticated API calls are rate-limited, you may want to create a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/authentication/authenticating-to-the-rest-api#authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token) for this purpose. For more details, see the [plugin's docs](https://facelessuser.github.io/MarkdownPreview/usage/#parsing-github-flavored-markdown).

*Sublime Text 3 only; support for ST2 was dropped in spring 2018.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using the [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org) (very useful). You said you [use Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17714/32657). You'll need to just install [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/), [`xsel`](https://github.com/kfish/xsel) and [`xclip`](https://github.com/astrand/xclip) packages. There are equivalents for Macs.

1. Copy your Markdown plaint text to clipboard
2. Run:

   ```
   xsel -b | pandoc -s -f markdown -t html | xclip -selection clipboard -t text/html | xsel -b
   ```
3. Paste the generated formatted text (for example on an email client, or LibreOffice).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Checked on Ubuntu 20.04. Important note on point 3: result must be pasted only to supported editors like OpenOffice Writer. To plaint text editors nothing will be pasted. I thought by mistake that this was because `xclip` is not properly working in my system.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jupyter Lab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab).

To install Jupyter Lab, type the following in your environment:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

After installation, browse to the location of your markdown file, right-click the file, select "Open With" then click "Markdown Preview".

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio Code, I use

> Markdown Preview Enhanced extension.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old perhaps someone was googling how to and reached here.
That is how I saw this question anyway.

You can use atom text editor and toggle markdown preview even in github style.

Press

```
ctrl+shift+m
```

The window will pop up or use Packages-->Markdown Preview.[image]

**Hope this helps someone**.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [static site editor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/static_site_editor/): with [GitLab 13.0 (May 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#wysiwyg-for-the-static-site-editor), it comes with a WYSIWYG panel.

> ### WYSIWYG for the Static Site Editor
>
> Markdown is a powerful and efficient syntax for authoring web content, but even seasoned authors of Markdown content can struggle to remember some of the less-frequently used formatting options or write even moderately-complex tables from scratch.
> There are some jobs better accomplished with a rich text, “What You See Is What You Get” (WYSIWYG) editor.
>
> **GitLab 13.0 brings a WYSIWYG Markdown authoring experience to the Static Site Editor with formatting options for common formatting options like headers, bold, italics, links, lists, blockquotes, and code blocks.**
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_0/wysiwyg-markdow-in-sse.png]
>
> The WYSIWYG editor also removes the onerous task of editing tables in Markdown by letting you visually edit table rows, columns and cells in the same way you would edit a spreadsheet. For those more comfortable writing in raw Markdown, there’s even a tab for switching between WYSIWYG and plain text editing modes.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/static_site_editor/#static-site-editor) and [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/214559/).

Again, you would use it only to write your `README`: once it looks good, you can report it back to your original project.
But the point is: you don't need no more any thrid-party markdown preview plugin.

---

And with [GitLab 14.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/08/22/gitlab-14-2-released/#preview-markdown-live-while-editing) (August 2021)

> ### Preview Markdown live while editing
>
> Markdown is a fast and intuitive syntax for writing rich web content. Until it isn’t.
> Luckily, it’s easy to preview the rendered output of Markdown to ensure the accuracy of your markup from the **Preview** tab.
>
> Unfortunately, the context switch required to move between the raw source code and the preview can be tedious and disruptive to your flow.
>
> Now, in both the Web IDE and single file editor, Markdown files have a new live preview option available. Right-click the editor and select **Preview Markdown** or use `Command/Control + Shift + P` to toggle a split-screen live preview of your Markdown content.
> The preview refreshes as you type, so you can be confident that your markup is valid and will render as you intended.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_2/create-markdown-live-preview.png -- Preview Markdown live while editing]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/web_ide/#markdown-editing) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/4859).

---

See [GitLab 14.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/12/22/gitlab-14-6-released/#toggle-wiki-editors-seamlessly) (December 2021)

> ### Toggle wiki editors seamlessly
>
> Toggle wiki editors seamlessly
>
> Editing wiki pages with the new rich Markdown editor makes it easier for everyone to contribute regardless of how well they know Markdown syntax.
> You may also prefer to write raw Markdown in some situations, but use the WYSIWYG interface for more complex or tedious formatting tasks, like creating tables.
>
> Previous versions of GitLab required you to save changes before switching between the rich Markdown editor and the Markdown source, adding more steps and friction to your edits.
>
> In GitLab 14.6 you can now seamlessly switch between the two editing experiences without committing your changes, choosing the editor that suits your needs at any given moment.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/wiki/#content-editor) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/342729).

---

See also [GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#default-split-view-for-markdown-preview-in-the-web-editor) (November 2022)

> ### Default split view for Markdown preview in the Web Editor
>
> The ability to preview Markdown files side by side while editing was [introduced](/releases/2021/08/22/gitlab-14-2-released/#preview-markdown-live-while-editing) in GitLab 14.2.
>
> With this release, we’ve made the split view the default experience for previewing Markdown in the Web Editor.
>
> In the **Preview** tab, you can now see a live Markdown preview that updates as you type alongside your content.
> This way, you can be confident that your markup is valid and renders as you intended without having to switch between the **Write** and **Preview** tabs.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/web_editor/#preview-markdown) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/378966).

Answer (score -1):

I just create a "feature" branch and push it to github where I make changes, which become visible exactly how they will look in github.

Then, when I'm satisfied, I rebase back to main or do a pull request to main, whichever process you happen to be using.

You rarely need to test locally when using git, unless your repository is behind a corp firewall, or need to work offline.

In such cases, both Atom and VScode have decent Markdown renderers, not good enough to show how your changes will look on github, but good enough to see if your changes are going in the right direction.