# Working with README.md on github.com

Tags: github, markdown, markup

I am not too familiar with the lightweight markup language used by github when updating README files.

Where are the resources which I can read up on how to write the appropriate markup syntax for my open source library's README/wiki files?

And is there a tool which I can "review my docs locally in my browser" before pushing the updated README to my github repository?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

The markup in question is coincidentally called **Markdown**, created by John Gruber, author of the [Daring Fireball blog](http://daringfireball.net/).  The original source of Markdown can be found at [Daring Fireball - Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

There are many Markdown dialects, the documentation for Github's can be found on the [Github Flavored Markdown](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/) page.

nice tip from that page:

press **M** on any Github page with a Markdown editor to reveal the cheatsheet.

You can also use the [Github Markdown Live Preview](http://tmpvar.com/markdown.html) page to test your Markdown documents.

**Update 2012-11-08**:  Efforts are underway to standardize the Markdown syntax.  See [The Future of Markdown - Jeff Atwood, Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/10/the-future-of-markdown.html) and [W3C Markdown Community Group](http://www.w3.org/community/markdown/).

**Update 2014-09-09**:  [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) a markdown standard and spec has been released.

Comment: The Github Markdown Live Preview doesn't render tables...

Comment: If your prefer a video screencast, I created one explaining Markdown here: http://mikemclin.net/markdown-syntax-language/

Comment: @Mike McLin Great Video explaining the syntax and the concepts behind! Great intro for the markdown newbie such as myself :)

Comment: [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) `-i my.md -w markdown_github -o my-github.md` converts an well-documented [extended markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example19/Pandoc_0027s-markdown.html) to github flovour.

Comment: The markdown live preview also doesn't seem to obey github's rules about underscores in the middle of words, e.g. my_setup_script.py will *not* italicize 'setup' in github but will in the previewer. 
It's useful, but just so people know.

Comment: Looks like github's markdown is complying with the new standard instead of it's own extensions and so tables have to be html and underscore is italic etc. This is really a bug of the documentation though. I don't feel like filing a bug now though.

Answer (score 11):

([Re-posting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694887/is-there-a-command-line-utility-for-rendering-github-flavored-markdown/13781363) with some edits.)

A little late to the game, but I wrote a small CLI in Python. It's called [Grip (Github Readme Instant Preview)](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip). Adding on to Patrick's answer, this will let you "review my docs locally in my browser."

Install it with:

```
$ pip install grip
```

And to use it, simply:

```
$ grip
```

Then visit `localhost:5000` to view the `readme.md` file at that location.

You can also specify your own file:

```
$ grip CHANGES.md
```

And change the port:

```
$ grip 8080
```

Or combine the previous two:

```
$ grip CHANGES.md 8080
```

You can even render GitHub-Flavored Markdown (i.e. how comments and issues are rendered), optionally with repo context to auto-hyperlink references to other issues:

```
$ grip --gfm --context=username/repo issue.md
```

For brevity, see the rest of the options and their details using the CLI help:

```
$ grip -h
```

Notable features:

- Renders pages to appear exactly like on GitHub
- Fenced blocks
- Python API
- Navigate between linked files
- Export a rendered document to a file

Hope this helps. [Check it out](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip).

Answer (score 5):

There's a nice online/live editor here:

http://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/

There's also a `Preview` button at GitHub.

See in the following screenshot that this button appears when I clicked Edit on `README.md`.

[image]

IMHO the live [editor](http://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/) is better than the current one available at GitHub.

**UPDATE**

Just now I found after searching for `Markdown` and Visual Studio that if you're using VS, you can install [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) and have `Markdown` support right from within Visual Studio. That's cool!

It has:

- Syntax highlighting =>
  Full colorization for Markdown syntax
- Intellisense for embedded languages (***W00T***) =>
  GitHub's embedded language feature is fully support by support for the ```language syntax.

[image]

- Preview window =>
  See a side-by-side preview window of the rendered HTML
- Compile to HTML =>
  Right-click any Markdown file and select Compile Markdown to HTML. This will generate a .html file nested under the Markdown file and it will stay in sync as the Markdown file changes.
- Custom Stylesheet =>
  You can add a solution specific Stylesheet to control the styles of the preview window.

Details about it [here](http://vswebessentials.com/features/markdown).

Answer (score 4):

Note that since February 2014, with "[Rendered Prose Diffs](https://github.com/blog/1784-rendered-prose-diffs)", you also can see the rendered version of a diff on a markdown file:

> Commits and pull requests including prose files now feature source **and rendered views**.

[image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/17715/1999080/7f0c15a2-853e-11e3-95dc-1d7737e1ec20.png]

> Non-text changes appear with a low-key dotted underline. Hover over the text to see what has changed:

[image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/17715/2005588/714cb5ea-86ef-11e3-9e92-a0d11ba6084f.png]

Answer (score 1):

Another option - Github's new text editor, Atom, will render github-flavoured markdown as you edit it. See https://atom.io/

I'm not sure whether it will be free (as in beer) in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, you can preview, as you edit the file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find that the other tools were good enough - I wanted:

1. Ability to edit offline
2. Not just regular markdown, but the actual *Github flavored markdown*

This is what I ultimately settled on: https://github.com/ypocat/gfms

```
> gfms

Github Flavored Markdown Server.
Run in your project's root directory.
Usage: gfms

Options:
  -p, --port              Port number to listen at.        [required]
  -h, --host              Host address to bind to.         [default: "localhost"]
  --proxy                 if behind a proxy, proxy url.
  -a, --api               Render using Github API.
  -n, --no-api-on-reload  Disable usage of Github API when the doc is manually reloaded.
```

So I've aliased:

```
alias gm='gfms -a -p 8070'
```

Using the `-p` option hits the Github API and uses the actual, current Github CSS so there aren't any surprises.