# How do I convert README.md to Github-styled HTML?

Tags: node.js, github, markdown

I have a README.md file (describing a Node app) that I need to convert to a self-contained Github-styled README.html.

Note that this is not the same as finding an HTML converter for Github-flavored markdown. The precise style is important, and so is the self-contained part. (This is how my question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694887/is-there-a-command-line-utility-for-rendering-github-flavored-markdown) one).

It can be an npm package or an online converter or perhaps some obscure (to me) Github feature allowing to view README.md full-screen, without the Github toolbar and such.

I can live with a Ruby gem or another language/platform if I have to. It needs to be simple, because I modify this README.md often.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a command line utility for rendering GitHub flavored Markdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694887/is-there-a-command-line-utility-for-rendering-github-flavored-markdown)

Comment: I saw that one. I have not checked every solution offered, but those I did check only parse github-flavored markdown, but don't apply github styling.

Comment: Is styling really that important? If one of those tools generates HTML, then I would imagine any CSS style could be applied

Comment: Not always. For instance, most HTML generators I see don't support language-specific index highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin for sublime text 2 that will do this for you, it is pretty darn accurate

https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview

There is also a github markdown API which you might be interested in: https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/

And the CSS: https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css

Answer (score 0):

I came to this post a few days ago. In the end, I could not find any tool that satisfied my needs so I decided to create my own.

[`ghmd` (GitHub Markdown)](https://pypi.org/project/ghmd/) is a minimal tool (~4 KB) that converts any Markdown file into HTML using the GitHub CSS. It supports both regular Mardkown and GitHub Flavored Mardkown, and adaptive, light and dark modes. The results look just like they would in GitHub.

To install it, just run:

```bash
pip install ghmd
```

And to convert any file:

```bash
ghmd README.md --embed-css
```

It will generate a `README.html` in the same directory as the original file. The `--embed-css` flag will embed the CSS styles in the HTML file so it is self-contained.

I use it a lot to send Markdown files as HTML and it works like a charm.