# Can github-pages work with only a .md, no .html no jekyll, like gist.github?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

Gist.github displays .md files with 0 effort on my part.
Can github pages do that too -- no user html, no jekyll ?
https://github.com/blog/2289-publishing-with-github-pages-now-as-easy-as-1-2-3 says

> 1. Create a repository (or navigate to an existing repository)
> 2. Commit a Markdown file via the web interface, just like you would any other file
> 3. Activate GitHub Pages via your repository's settings
>      And that's it
>      ...
>      We'll use your README file as the site's index if you don't have an index.md (or index.html)

But this doesn't seem to work, or I've misunderstood.
Has anyone else tried this flow ?
Symptom:

```
Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the /docs folder in the master branch
Your site is published at https://denis-bz.github.io/test-gh-pages/
```

hangs -- 404, hours later.

Master/docs under https://github.com/denis-bz/test-gh-pages
looks ok, to a git dummy;
the same .md renders fine on 
[gist.github](https://gist.github.com/c62ee57040100c752d35) .

What didn't work:

```
git --version
    # git version 2.2.1
echo "# test-gh-pages `isotime`" > README.md
touch .nojekyll docs/.nojekyll

git init
git add README.md .nojekyll docs/.nojekyll docs/Gish.md
git commit -m "docs/Gish.md `isotime`"
    # github.com/new test-gh-pages
git remote add origin https://github.com/denis-bz/test-gh-pages.git
git push -v --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: Why are you trying to disable Jekyll? What is your end goal?

Comment: @Kevin Workman, simplicity: Jekyll seems to be unnecessary, see
https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages 
Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577147/how-to-fix-page-404-on-github-page
with quite a few solutions, some voodoo

Comment: What content do you want to have? Is it `.md` files that you want to process into HTML? Is it just HTML files that you want left alone? Something else?

Comment: @Kevin Workman, I'd like to see the .md just like on gist.github -- changed the top part to say that. Just this minute a nice Github staff guy emailed "remove the .nojekyll and add an index.md"; trying that. Thanks

Comment: Right, if you want to render your `.md` files as nice formatted HTML pages, then that's exactly what Jekyll does for you. You don't want to get rid of Jekyll in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`master/docs/index.md` alone, with no `index.html` and no `.nojekyll`, works:

```
# github.com/new: make a new repo test-gh-pages
mkdir docs
cp -p .../my.md docs/index.md
echo "# test-gh-pages `isotime`" > README.md

git init
git add README.md docs/index.md
git commit -m "docs/index.md `isotime`"
git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/test-gh-pages.git
git push -v --set-upstream origin master

# github.com/<user>/test-gh-pages settings: GitHub Pages master branch /docs
# (don't forget save)

Your GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the /docs folder in the master branch
```

Apparently this calls
[Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) to turn the `docs/index.md` into .html
for browsers to display (in a hidden cache ? on-the-fly ? don't know).
After 10 minutes you should see

```
Your site is published at https://<user>.github.io/test-gh-pages/
```

See also 
[is-there-a-command-line-utility-for-rendering-github-flavored-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694887/is-there-a-command-line-utility-for-rendering-github-flavored-markdown/13781363#13781363)
: [grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip)  .

Thanks, GitHub support.

Comment: Do note that this also injects a bunch of SEO code into the HTML header, which you won't be able to turn off without dramatically more configuration.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, is there a simpler way, or an overview of the process ? Also with MathJax in github markdown ? Thanks

Comment: You'd be looking at a slightly more involved process, see https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages-and-jekyll#configuring-jekyll-in-your-github-pages-site