# How to configure 'less' to show formatted markdown files?

Tags: linux, shell, markdown, gnu, text-processing

I would like to have `less` display `*.md` markdown files with some formatting -- like I know `less` can, for manpages, etc. I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

I am as far as putting a *user defined filter* into `.lessfilter`:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
  *.md)
    fn=/tmp/$1.$$.html
    markdown "$1" | html2txt > $fn  ### LOSES FORMATTING
    cat $fn                         ### TO STDOUT???
    ;;
  *)
  # We don't handle this format
  exit 1
esac
# No further processing by lesspipe necessary
exit 0
```

So, the main questions are:

- How can I pass some basic formatting information to `less` as well, instead of losing it with `html2txt`
- Is it correct to just print the new content to *stdout*? Or could I just write the `*.html` to file disk and let `less` handle that html at its own digression (seeing the html-extension and acting on it?)

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). It can convert files from markdown format to groff man pages which you can then view in `man`.

Your `.lessfilter` script would be:

```
case "$1" in
  *.md)
    pandoc -s -f markdown -t man "$1" | man -l -
    ;;
```

Alternatively, convert it to html using the `markdown` command and then use the `lynx` browser to view it, but this didn't work too well for me.

```
case "$1" in
  *.md)
    markdown "$1" | lynx -stdin
    ;;
```

And, yes, the `lessfilter` script must write to stdout.

Comment: actually, the `markdown "$1" | html2text` version works best, because I get ascii-art boldface etc that way. The `pandoc|man`-variant basically works, but every format is lost. I guess, because the ouput goes into a pipe for `less`, and that prevents `man` to do any formatting. The `markdown|lynx`-variant does not do anything, maybe because `lynx` is interactive? I just get the original file shown.

Answer (score 6):

Dogbane's answer is great, but if you use `groff -T utf8 -man` instead of `man -l` to do the formatting, then the bold, italic, etc. come through. As seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20197316/2674930.

Answer (score 6):

This didn't work on my version of MacOSX (10.10.5 Yosemite).  The man page doesn't mention a `.lessfilter` either.  Here is what I did (after reading MAN page - thanks to this question for the prompt and hints).

I created the scripts `lessopen.sh` and `lessclose.sh` in my `~/bin`.  Respectively they are:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  *.md)
    pandoc -s -f markdown -t man "$1" | groff -T utf8 -man > /tmp/less.$$
    if [ -s /tmp/less.$$ ]; then
        echo /tmp/less.$$
    else
        rm -f /tmp/less.$$
    fi
    ;;
esac
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
rm $2
```

The return from the `lessopen.sh` is the name of the file with the contents to `less`en.  Or if nothing then the original file is used.  The `-s` tests if the file is NOT zero size.  The `lessclose.sh` cleans up.

Then in my ~/.bash_profile is:

```
export LESSOPEN="lessopen.sh %s"
export LESSCLOSE="less-close.sh %s %s"
```

I also had to install pandoc - groff already existed

```
brew install pandoc
```

Then simply:

```
less README.md
```

to read it rendered.

Comment: If you want to show tables, you can switch `-f markdown` to `-f gfm` and add `-t` to `groff`. Example: `pandoc -s -f gfm -t man "$1" | groff -t -T utf8 -man > /tmp/less.$$`