# Using .lessfilter

Tags: bash, zsh

I've seen several programmers using ./lessfilter filtes for preprocessing files before being feeded to less.
However my less doesn't seem to recognize my .lessfilter file in ~.
What am I doing wrong? My manpage of less doesn't mention it.

```
$ less —version
less 481 (POSIX regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2015  Mark Nudelman
```

Comment: Read the section "input preprocessor" in the man page, especially about the `LESSOPEN` environment variable.

Comment: It is mentioned in the man page of lesspipe on Debian: http://unix.com/man-page/linux/1/lesspipe

Comment: There is a nice example of how to use `.lessfilter` on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38494086/205696. The example is for macOS but works fine on Linux for me. Spoiler alert, `.lessfilter` can be called what-ever you want.

Comment: There is also an excellent answer https://superuser.com/a/71593/279100 of using GNU Source-highlight with `LESSOPEN` environment variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noting the comment: the [`less` manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/less.1.html) does not mention `.lessfilter`, and it is not a feature of `less` (see [source code](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html)).

Instead, it is used in some examples which set the `LESSOPEN` variable to a script.  Here are a few places where that is mentioned:

- [Debian #205702: lesspipe: Please consider using a more powerful version](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=205702) (2006)
  Says this comes from http://sf.net/projects/lesspipe
- [dot-files/lessfilter](https://github.com/suriya/dot-files/blob/master/lessfilter) (2007)
- [Diff of /sys-apps/less/files/lesspipe.sh](https://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/sys-apps/less/files/lesspipe.sh?r1=1.28&r2=1.29) (2008)
- [my package of the day: less (yes, less)](http://www.screenage.de/blog/2008/06/03/my-package-of-the-day-less-yes-less-2/) (2008)
- [Howto add colors support for less](http://www.speedblue.org/less_color.php) (2008, perhaps)
- [Peter Eisentraut's Blog](http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2009/07/adding-color-to-console-code-syntax.html) (2009)
- [Get colors in 'less'' command](https://superuser.com/a/337640/441480) (2011, apparently crediting a page from 2008 no longer available *"Using Pygments with less"*)
- [Offered: .lessfilter using pygments](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/802/offered-lessfilter-using-pygments) (2012)
- [Changelog for less-458-7.fc20.x86_64.rpm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/22/idpl/25988008/com/changelog.html)
  Thu Apr 11 2013 Fridolin Pokorny - 458-2- Added gpg support to lesspipe.sh (#885122)- Added ~/.lessfilter support (#885122)

So you may have seen this feature in a Fedora package, or seen someone using it based on the several places it was described, but it is not generally part of `less`.

Comment: It is mentioned in the man page of `lesspipe` on Debian: http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/lesspipe/