# Text codepage in groff

Tags: groff, troff

How to setup a correct codepage in `groff`?
For example to use a cyrillic language.

Man page notes about `-T` switch. But `troff -T utf8 -ms troff_file.txt`
gives:

```
warning: invalid input character code 128`
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. Please, uploade your `troff_file.txt`.  By the way, the best place for help with `Groff` is the mailing list (https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/groff/).

Answer (score 1):

`-Tutf8` only selects the *output* device. If you want `groff` to accept *Unicode* input, use the [`-K`](http://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Groff-Options.html#Groff-Options) switch.

Another way to have Cyrillic is simply to use `Tlatin1` to enable eight-bit character codes, and feed `groff` a source file in a single-byte encoding such as `CP 1251` or `KOI8-R`. Don't forget to prepare your hyphenation file accordingly.